# jaxb: strange class cast exception on enum list

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, java-8, oxm

I am using `jaxb` to generate java classes from an `xsd` file. The `xsd` contains a definition of an element of which the content is a list of constants defined in the same `xsd` as enumeration.

When the classes are generated using the JAXB reference implementation from the oracle's `jdk1.7` (`v2.2.4-2`) it is possible to iterate over the list of enums and assign them the variables of the same type.

However, when the classes are generated using oracle's `jdk1.8` (build `1.8.0_45-b15` - latest as of posting date) JAXB reference implementation (`v2.2.8-b130911.1802`) it is no longer possible to assign the elements of the list to variable of the enum type.

Any attempt to assign or iterate using enhanced for loop ends with a `ClassCastException`

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to so.jaxb.enums.generated.GConstNameType
    at so.jaxb.enums.domain.TestReader.readTest(TestReader.java:36)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

The list itself is in both cases parameterized with the correct enum type.

Here is a code reproducing the problem described above:

**XSD file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:tns="http://www.foo.com/xmlns/test"
    targetNamespace="http://www.foo.com/xmlns/test"
    attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:simpleType name="GConstType">
        <xs:list itemType="tns:GConstNameType" />
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="GConstNameType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="FOO" />
            <xs:enumeration value="BAR" />
            <xs:enumeration value="BAZ" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:complexType name="TestType">
        <xs:all>
            <xs:element name="const-name-list" 
                type="tns:GConstType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
        </xs:all>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:element name="test" type="tns:TestType" />

</xs:schema>
```

**Test XML file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<t:test xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:t="http://www.foo.com/xmlns/test"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <t:const-name-list>FOO BAR</t:const-name-list>

</t:test>
```

**Test reader**

```
public class TestReader {

    @Test
    public void readTest() throws IOException {
        try (InputStream xml = TestReader.class
                .getResourceAsStream("/so/jaxb/enums/resources/test.xml");
            InputStream xsd = TestReader.class
                .getResourceAsStream("/so/jaxb/enums/resources/test.xsd")) {
            TestType testType = fromXML(TestType.class, xml, xsd);
            List<GConstNameType> constNameList = testType.getConstNameList();
            for(Object constName : constNameList) {
                System.out.println(constName.getClass().getName());
            }
            for(GConstNameType constName : constNameList) {
                System.out.println(constName);
            }
        }
    }

    public static <T> T fromXML(Class<T> _class, InputStream xml, InputStream xsd) {
        XMLStreamReader xsr = null;
        try {
            Source xmlSource = new StreamSource(xml);
            Source xsdSource = new StreamSource(xsd);
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(_class);
            Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
            Schema schema = SchemaFactory
                .newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI).newSchema(xsdSource);
            unmarshaller.setSchema(schema);
            xsr = XMLInputFactory.newInstance().createXMLStreamReader(xmlSource);
            JAXBElement<T> jaxbElement = unmarshaller.unmarshal(xsr, _class);
            return jaxbElement.getValue();
        } catch (JAXBException | SAXException | XMLStreamException | FactoryConfigurationError e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } finally {
            try {
                if(xsr != null) {
                    xsr.close();   
                }
            } catch(XMLStreamException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output jdk1.7**

```
so.jaxb.enums.generated.GConstNameType
so.jaxb.enums.generated.GConstNameType
FOO
BAR
```

**Output jdk1.8**

```
java.lang.String
java.lang.String
<ClassCastException>
```

From the output above it is clear that elements of the type `java.lang.String` are smuggled into the list `List<GConstNameType>` or that a List of `String`s  is set instead of a `GConstNameType`s List. Anyhow the `String` enums names from the xml file are not mapped to java enum constants.

The java runtime is in both cases the same, it's the `jre` from the `jdk1.8`.

The commands used for generation:

```
C:\Oracle\Java\jdk1.7\bin\xjc.exe D:\dev\java\Tests\src\so\jaxb\enums\resources\test.xsd -b D:\dev\java\Tests\src\so\jaxb\enums\resources -d D:\dev\java\Tests/src -p so.jaxb.enums.generated -extension
```

and

```
C:\Oracle\Java\jdk1.8\bin\xjc.exe D:\dev\java\Tests\src\so\jaxb\enums\resources\test.xsd -b D:\dev\java\Tests\src\so\jaxb\enums\resources -d D:\dev\java\Tests/src -p so.jaxb.enums.generated -extension
```

- How is this possibles / What is happening here?
- Is the schema definition shown above not correct for defining an enumeration?
- How to work around this problem without having to use an `XmlAdapter` (a way that would work on every jdk version)?

---

**EDIT**

The only code difference between both generated packages

[image: The only code difference between both generated packages]

Removing the annotation

```
@XmlSchemaType(name = "anySimpleType")
```

renders the `jdk1.8` generated code fully functional.

- Why is the newer `JAXB` implementation mapping the enum to `anySimpleType`?

Comment: Have you tried using *<xs:restriction base="xs:token">* instead of *<xs:restriction base="xs:string">* ? It seems that Java8 is less lenient on what a XML string could or could not be.

Comment: @medveshonok117 tried with `xs:token` as suggested but `xcj` is still generating `@XmlSchemaType(name = "anySimpleType")` which leads to the `ClassCastException`.

Comment: Issue in the JAXB GH project: https://github.com/gf-metro/jaxb/issues/21

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can change your xsd to:

```
 <xs:complexType name="TestType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="const-name-list">
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:list itemType="tns:GConstNameType"/>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:simpleType name="GConstNameType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value="FOO"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="BAR"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="BAZ"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

this is working on java 8.

the new parser has some new restrications.

**UPDATE**: for your comment you can use this:

```
<xs:complexType name="TestType">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="tns:ListType">
            <xs:sequence/>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="ListType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="const-name-list">
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:list itemType="tns:GConstNameType"/>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="SecondTestType">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="tns:ListType">
            <xs:sequence/>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:simpleType name="GConstNameType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value="FOO"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="BAR"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="BAZ"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. While this works around the issue, I find it not very smart to have to define the type inline each time it is needed rather than defining once and referencing it using the attribute _type="..."_. Can you elaborate more on those _restrictions_? Is there any specification that tells that enum lists now have to be defined like this (imho both definitions are equivalent)? In any way, I would call the fact that generating a list of `String`s and injecting into a list of `GConstNameType` is rathaer a bug than a restriction. Restrictions work the other way around ;-)

Comment: @A4L you mean the definition of the list?

Comment: yes, the simple type `GConstType` which in your version is anonymous since inlined.

Comment: @A4L I put up-to-date xsd.

Comment: Hey, I saw your update but didn't had the time to evaluate it. Your second suggestion works too, but I find the first variant better since it alters the original `xsd` only in a minimal way, in comparison to the second one. I will accept your answer since it provides a workaround that results in working generated code from both versions of `xjc`. No bounty awarded since no further explanations are provided :(, but anyways thank you again for your time and help!